# Only valid in object module

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm getting this error:

> only valid in object module

when I'm trying to run the script below on VBA outlook 2016.

```
Private WithEvents myItem As outlook.MailItem

Private Sub myItem_AttachmentRead(ByVal myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment)

 If myAttachment.Type = olByValue Then

 MsgBox "If you change this file, also save your changes to the original file."

 End If

End Sub


Public Sub TestAttachRead()

 Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments

 Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

 Set myItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items("Test")

 Set atts = myItem.Attachments

 myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?640709-RESOLVED-Outlook-WithEvents-Compile-Error-quot-Only-valid-in-object-module-quot)

Comment: I mange to get it work, but now the event is not happening...
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following vba code Must be under ThisOutlookSession module*

```
Private WithEvents myItem As outlook.MailItem
Private Sub myItem_AttachmentRead(ByVal myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment)

 If myAttachment.Type = olByValue Then

 MsgBox "If you change this file, also save your changes to the original file."

 End If

End Sub
```

*And the following vba code could be on regular module*

```
Public Sub TestAttachRead()

 Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments

 Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

 Set myItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items("Test")

 Set atts = myItem.Attachments

 myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: I added all to ThisOutlookSession module and it's wokring great!
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming this code is currently on a standard VBA module. You cannot have an `WithEvents` variable on such modules. It must be either a class module or a document module (e.g. one of Outlook's code-behind for instance) in order to receive events from that mail item.

Comment: You shouldn't be. I verified it does work pasted in a class module. Are you sure you actually inserted a class module? Try using the `Insert` menu which has `Class Module` and `Module` both listed and choosing the `Class Module`.