# Script execution after receiving email / outlook / VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2019

```
Sub WorkWithEmails(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oLookItem As Object
Dim oLookMail As MailItem
Dim oLookFldr As Folder
Dim oLookName As NameSpace
Dim Ret_Val

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oLookName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oLookFldr = oLookName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oLookItem In oLookFldr.Items
    If TypeOf oLookItem Is MailItem Then
        Debug.Print oLookItem.Subject
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.ReceivedTime
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.Sender
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.SenderEmailAddress
        Debug.Print oLookItem.Body
        Ret_Val = Shell("path\Python37\python.exe " & "path\draft.py" & " -t " & oLookItem.Subject & " -d " & oLookItem.Body)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This code terminates with an error, because if I understood correctly, the rule is triggered earlier (event) than the letter appears in the folder

I tried:

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub WorkWithEmails(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Sleep (5000)
...
```

And

```
...
Sleep (5000)
For Each oLookItem In oLookFldr.Items
```

in this case, nothing happens when a new letter is received.

If you run, `Sub WorkWithEmails()`, then you work out everything perfectly (provided that the letter is in the folder).

draft.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t")
parser.add_argument("-d")
args = parser.parse_args()

f = open('path/logs/jira.log', 'a')
f.write(str(datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')) + ':' + args.t + ', ' + args.d + '\n')
f.close()
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: there is either no error, or "array bounds"

Comment: The ItemAdd event is triggered after the item is in a folder. "... if I understood correctly, the rule is triggered earlier (event) than the letter appears in the folder"

Comment: @niton when using the code in the response from your link - `Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items` Compile Error: Only valid in object module

Comment: The answer is complete. If necessary there is more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913002/only-valid-in-object-module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720620/how-to-apply-withevents-trigger and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494601/why-does-my-withevent-doesnt-work-in-outlook-vba